# How to show message in admin account if the users do some operation in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

I am currently developing an odoo module to book meeting rooms.. If a user book a meeting room then an informative message or popup message with booking details should be send to the admin. Also this message shouldn't be viewed by user. How can i do this? Anyone knows any method, please share

Comment: _inherit = ['mail.thread'] in your module adds the messages like sale orders for example. Is it enough?

Answer (score 0):

What i have done is..

Add mail dependency in openerp file.

```
'depends': ['base','mail']
```

Inherit [mail.thread] in models where you want to get the notifications.

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread']
```

Add these two fields in the form view of the corresponding model...

```
<field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
<field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
```